# How to evoke R home directory in file name construction?

Tags: r, environment-variables, home-directory

I'm using R under Windows XP. It picked up the environmental variable HOME from windows which is,

```
> Sys.getenv("R_USER")
R_USER 
"H:"
```

However, how can I use that variable quickly in a file name? In particular, if I have a file stored at `H:/tmp/data.txt`. How should I construct the following command?

```
data <- read.table("$R_HOME/tmp/data.txt")
```

That one clearly didn't work.

The only way I got it to work is the following:

```
data <- read.table(paste(Sys.getenv("R_USER"), "/tmp/data.txt", sep = ""))
```

Which is so cumbersome that I have to believe there is an easier way. Does anyone know a quick evocation of the HOME variable in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I got it. it's just

```
data <- read.table("~/tmp/data.txt")
```

Comment: See `?file.path` for a more general method of constructing file paths, e.g., `file.path("~", "tmp", "data.txt")`.